# Why does += add the sum int. of one list to another and not just +?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
sales_data = [[12, 17, 22], [2, 10, 3], [5, 12, 13]]
scoops_sold = 0
```

I originally wrote:

```
for location in sales_data:
  print(location)
  for element in location: 
    scoops_sold + element 
    print(scoops_sold)
```

After messing around I saw I was just missing an `=` after the `+` sign.

Why does `+=` add the sum int. of one list to another and not just `+`?

Comment: Note that your question is fundamentally about `+` vs. `+=`, which is unrelated to looping. You'd have the same problem with no loops at all so I edited that out of your question. Hope it helps!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  This is basic Python syntax.  Stack Overflow is not intended as a tutorial resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, all of the previous answers, including the accepted answer, are entirely **misleading**, note the difference between these two **different** python constructs:

1. The `+` operator, generates a **new** list from the two operands:

   ```
   >>> a = b = [1]
   >>> a = a + [2]
   >>> a, b
   [1, 2], [1]
   ```

   Here, both `a` and `b` are initially pointing to the **same** list.  Then we have created a **new** list and rebound it to the variable `a`
2. The `+=` operator, modifies an **existing list**

   ```
   >>> a = b = [1]
   >>> a += [2]
   >>> a, b
   [1, 2], [1, 2]
   ```

   Here, both `a` and `b` are initially pointing to the **same** list.  Then we have modified this same list.

The takeaway ... the syntax `a = a + b` is **not short for** `a += b`

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I deleted my answer and upvoted yours. Please note that by focussing entirely on this technical inaccuracy, you're ignoring the core issue with OP's code, i.e. discarding the new list.

Answer (score 0):

`+=` is short for `scoops_sold = scoops_sold + element`. Having `scoops_sold + element` is computing the result but not storing it to any variable where as `scoops_sold = scoops_sold + element` is computing the result and assigning it to scoops_sold.

Comment: No this is **wrong** ... `scoops_sold = scoops_sold + element` is **semantically different** to `scoops_sold += element`.  Try the following : `a = b = [1,2]; b+= [3]` versus `a = b = [1,2]; b = b + [3]` and inspect the value of `a` in both cases.